# Updating values in a column in pandas dataframe using itself and values in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that can be simplified like that:

```
event = ['NaN', 'SRNeg', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'SINeg', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'NaN']
scores = random.randint(100, size=(10))
TR = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'event':event, 'scores':scores, 'TR':TR})
```

I want to modify the dataframe such that whenever the value in `event` is of interest (in this case 'SRNeg' and 'SINeg'), I want to assign the corresponding events of the following two TRs with the same value. This is the example output:

```
event = ['NaN', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'SRNeg', 'NaN', 'NaN', 'SINeg', 'SINeg', 'SINeg', 'NaN']
scores = random.randint(100, size=(10)) # same values as before
TR = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
df = pd.DataFrame({'event':event, 'scores':scores, 'TR':TR})
```

Does anyone know of an elegant way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: Use real NaNs and `ffill(limit=2)`

Comment: Something like `df['event'] = df['event'].where(df['event'].isin(['SINeg', 'SRNeg'])).ffill(limit=2).fillna(df['event'])`

Comment: I don't think `bfill` or `ffill` is the best way to achieve this. The key issue is that `ffill()` will fill all subsequent NaN until it encounters a non-NaN value. Alternative: `df.loc[df['event'].shift(-1).isin(['SRNeg', 'SINeg']), 'event'] = df['event'].shift(-1)` and `df.loc[df['event'].shift(-2).isin(['SRNeg', 'SINeg']), 'event'] = df['event'].shift(-2)`.